# generate POCo objects with data based on data difference

Tags: c#, sql-server, code-generation, sql-server-data-tools

I think have a bit strange question. Looking for some kind of opensource software/tools to do next code generation task.

In SSDT it possible to generate data difference script between two databases etc.

However, I would like to create a C# script which will represent that data insert/update/date in plain POCo objects (POC classes generated from SQL server scheme, DB schema the same between two DB).

For example. I have classes:

```
        class  User{
          public Int Id{get; set;}
          public String Name{get; set; }
       }
```

SSDT geenrated SQL script:

```
        INSERT INTO User (Id, Name) VALUES (5, 'UserA')          
        INSERT INTO User (Id, Name) VALUES (3, 'UserB')
```

I would like to generate next code:

```
       userRepo.Insert( new User(){ Id = 5, Name = 'UserA'} )
       userRepo.Insert( new User(){ Id = 3, Name = 'UserB'} )
```

Is there any existing projects for that task ?
Thank you,

Comment: you can achieve that with T4 templates

Comment: Right, I did suspect that. So the question now what will be the source of data diff between two DB? I did try to use liquibase and I am sure SSDT could provide some output in XML format. But is there some opensource tool at the moment?

Comment: you can use c# code there and do the output in any format you would like

Comment: Thank your for your response! We decided to go for manual implementation so far. Idea I have mentioned is good but will take quite a time to implement as I understand.